# Share Spring Security Context across multiple http sections

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a situation where I have the basic application being served on the main endpoint (/**). I use spring security to authenticate the user before serving any further resources. The authentication is done with a login form.

But specifically the endpoint (/lti/**) is being used in a different Http Section. There, Spring security handles the authentication using OAuth.

After authentication on the /lti/** endpoint, the user is expected to load my entire application in an iFrame. This means access to all resources protected by the 1st Http-section.

Now the problem here is even though the user authenticated using OAuth creds for loading the app from /lti/**, and I set all appropriate user roles, when the application loads in the iFrame and tries to access any resources, it redirects to the login screen as directed by the 1st Http-section (The succeeding calls are through AJAX if that helps, but you can see the response in the dev tools).

Based on my research so far, the Security Context is not shared among different entry points. Different firewalls are instantiated so the Security context itself is re-initiated.

Here's a bit of my Security context:

```
<security:http pattern="/lti/**" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="oAuthProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <security:headers>
        <security:frame-options disabled="true"/>
    </security:headers>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_OAUTH')"/>

    <!-- Filter -->
    <security:custom-filter ref="oAuthProcessingFilter" before="ANONYMOUS_FILTER"/>
    <!-- Disable CSRF -->
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
</security:http>

<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url ... />
     ....
    <security:form-login
            authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
            login-page=............"/>
    <security:logout ................./>
    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="............." session-authentication-error-url="................">
    </security:session-management>
    <!-- Enable csrf protection -->
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>
```

Any approach that will work or have any ideas how I ccan tackle the situation?

Answer (score 0):

SecurityContext is populated in every request, the FilterChain set it up at the beginning of the request by using the **SecurityContextPersistenceFilter**. By deafult, this filter store the authentication data in the HttpSession.

The users are authenticated in a page an then you load an Iframe which starts a different HttpSession (you could check this if you watch the sessionids).

Then you have several options:

1. Do not use an Iframe. The best option, if it is not a must.
2. Configure a default RememberMe filter. the problem is that the users will be remembered in each session, until the cookie expires.
3. Store the SecurityContext in a more persistent way than the session.

Summarizing, I think that your problem is not about different entry points, its about different sessions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this approach. I have to use OAuth 1.0 but the approach might work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem and I misunderstood your answer too. The problem is not with having the user to login again with every request. If you re-read the problem, it's only a problem when the context changes from /lti/** to /** from iFrame. The sessions are not shared hence the context.